# SQL Server 2008 : CASE WHEN auto increments/groups data

Tags: sql-server-2008, case, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a table that stores data like the below :

```
MonthOpened | MONTH | Collected 
--------------------------------
01/05/2012  |   1   | £10.00 
01/05/2012  |   2   | £30.00 
01/05/2012  |   3   | £30.00 
01/05/2012  |   4   | £30.00 
01/05/2012  |   5   | £30.00 
01/05/2012  |   6   | £10.00 
01/05/2012  |   7   | £30.00 
01/05/2012  |   8   | £50.00 
01/05/2012  |   9   | £10.00 
01/05/2012  |   10  | £50.00 
01/05/2012  |   11  | £100.00 
01/05/2012  |   12  | £141.92 
01/05/2012  |   13  | £100.00 
01/05/2012  |   14  | £50.00
```

Month opened is the date the accounts where taken out, Month is the month that they paid (month 1 is the month the account was opened (may), month 2 would be June, month 3 would be july and so on. At the moment this goes all the way through to month 36.

For reference this data goes into a SSRS Matrix and appears like so

```
MONTH     |1     |2     |     3|     4|     5|     6|     7|     8|     9|    10|     11|     12|     13|    14
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01/05/2012|£10.00|£30.00|£30.00|£30.00|£30.00|£10.00|£30.00|£50.00|£10.00|£50.00|£100.00|£141.92|£100.00|£50.00
```

I've been asked to group these together after 12 months, **so 1-12 appear, then 18, 24, 30, 36 and so on**. I've done this as a quick fix by doing a generic case when

```
CASE 
   WHEN ISNULL(sp.Month, N'01') BETWEEN 01 AND 12 
      THEN ISNULL(sp.Month, N'01')
   WHEN ISNULL(sp.Month, N'01') BETWEEN 13 AND 18 
      THEN 18
   WHEN ISNULL(sp.Month, N'01') BETWEEN 19 AND 24 
      THEN 24
   WHEN ISNULL(sp.Month, N'01') BETWEEN 25 AND 30 
      THEN 30
   WHEN ISNULL(sp.Month, N'01') BETWEEN 31 AND 36 
      THEN 36
   ELSE '' 
END AS MONTH
```

However I need to get it so that it auto groups so that it takes in account future months (42, 48, 54, 60....) but I need to be able to do this in the SSRS query window and havent been able to find a way of getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to group by every 12th, then doing an *integer* division of 12 on the month subtracted by 1, will give you the interval they belong to.
You can then group by that interval.

For example:
Month 1 will be `(1-1) / 12 = 0` and this will be your first interval
Month 2 will be `(2-1) / 12 = 0` Still first interval
Month 13 will be `(13 - 1) / 12 = 1` The beginning of second interval
Month 36 will be `(36 -1) / 12 = 2` The beginning of third interval

And so forth? That way you do not have to case indefinitely.

Comment: @allan-s-hansen I need to be able to display the first 12 months on there own, then group by every 6 after the 12 month

Comment: If the interval is only 6 months, then you can do the division with 6 to get interval numbers. If you then want to omit the first 12 (2 intervals), then do it with a case. But doing the division so you can get the interval programmatically should help you simplify the query